# How to debug "unrecognized selector sent to instance" in Swift while the method is not implemented

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have 2 UITextFields in my current view controller. The problem I encounter is when I finish typing in one TextField and try to move the cursor to the other, my app crashed.

I've set up my view controller to implement UITextFieldDelegate. Set the delegate of the two TextFields to be self and implement the **textFieldShouldReturn** method.

The error message I got is:

> [Snapagram.SnapViewController disableEditing:]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x7fabdc55d700.

What I've tried is to use Exception breakpoint, but it only returns to the 1st line of AppDelegate. So I don't know which part of my code to post. Plus, I don't even have **disableEditing** anywhere in my code. My question are

1. how can I see which object is calling this method
2. why is this method being called, despite me not having implemented it

**Edit:**

this is the entire view controller code, the **textFieldShouldReturn** is at the bottom.

```
import UIKit

class SnapViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {


    var chosenThread: Thread!
    var entry: ThreadEntry!
    var post: Post!
    var imageToDisplay: UIImage!

    @IBOutlet weak var threadCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var createButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageDisplayed: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var captionField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var postButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        imageDisplayed.image = imageToDisplay!
        super.viewDidLoad()
        postButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
        createButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0

        threadCollectionView.delegate = self
        threadCollectionView.dataSource = self

        captionField.delegate = self
        locationField.delegate = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return feed.threads.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let index = indexPath.item
        let thread = feed.threads[index]

        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "chooseThreadCell", for: indexPath) as? ChooseThreadCollectionViewCell {
            cell.emojiLabel.text = thread.emoji
            cell.nameLabel.text = thread.name
            return cell
        } else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        chosenThread = feed.threads[indexPath.item]
        entry = ThreadEntry(username: feed.username, image: imageToDisplay)
    }


    @IBAction func createPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        chosenThread.addEntry(threadEntry: entry)
    }

    @IBAction func postPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        post = Post(location: locationField.text!, image: imageToDisplay, user: feed.username, caption: captionField.text!, date: Date())
        feed.addPost(post: post)
    }
}

extension SnapViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your ** textFieldShouldReturn** code and other related codes

Comment: Let's find out _when_ the crash occurs. Put a breakpoint on `self.view.endEditing(true)` and run the app. Do whatever you do to hit the breakpoint. Step over, step over. Did we crash? In other words, is that line the cause?

Comment: I've got another wild and crazy suggestion. In that line, change `true` to `false`. Does that make a difference?

Comment: "how can I see which object is calling this method" There actually is a really cool way to do that; it's called a _symbolic breakpoint_. We'll resort to that if we can't solve this by guesswork. :)

Comment: "What I've tried is to use Exception breakpoint" OK, that was good, but it sounds to me like you configured the exception breakpoint on catch rather than on throw.

Comment: Apart from that, the question provides insufficient information to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @matt my Exception break point returns to the line of  `self.view.endEditing(true)` when I hit return on that text field, and the error message is saying `[Snapagram.SnapViewController disableEditing:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fabdc55d700.` (with the instance being self, the SnapViewController". But I still don't understand why the method is being called on this view controller while I don't have the `disableEditing:` method at all. Any suggestions on how I can proceed?

Comment: Well, as I said, I can’t reproduce the issue. It might help if you could reduce this to a minimal project and post it, as you are not providing instructions on how to reproduce this crash.